# Is a dashed parametric circle possible?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using parametric circles like

```
fx(u,v)=r*cos(v)
fy(u,v)=r*sin(v)
fz(u,v)=0
```

and I want some of them to be dashed. Is that somhow possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a dashed curve you need a terminal compatible with dashes. The shape of the curve is irrelevant here. The usual terminal, `wxt`, can be used with the `dashed` option:

```
set term wxt dashed
set parametric
set size ratio -1
r = 1.
plot r*cos(t),r*sin(t) lt 2 lc 1
```

[image]

Comment: in addition to your answer i needed a dashtype with more space between the dashes `dt ".   ."`, else it looks like a solid line and thanks :D

Comment: You can access different dash styles by changing the number that follows `lt`. Also, you can change the default dash length when setting the terminal: `set term wxt dashed dashlength 10`.